# Why does HATEOAS not specify a schema for the request body

Tags: api, rest, hateoas, hypermedia

A question for this already exists, but is more tech focused and doesnt have answers: [Representing a request body on HATEOAS link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71912090/representing-a-request-body-on-hateoas-link)

I like HATEOAS. I love using it in my frontend to check if I can perform some actions by checking if a link exists instead of having business logic.

But what I do not understand is how HATEOAS can truly be useful in other scenario's. What if you have an "AddItemToBasket" link which would need a request body with some properties in it. The frontend would still need to know what this request body looks like. But HATEOAS doesn't tell you this.

This means you still have a dependency on API knowledge. I think lots of applications solve this problem with generated API clients/graphql, but that makes HATEOAS a hard sell.

Why use HATEOAS if we can't use the URL and http method, because it doesn't offer the full picture.

Answer (score 2):

REST builds on standards (uniform interface constraint) and currently there is no standard way to do this. There is a [Hydra W3C WorkGroup](https://www.hydra-cg.com/) writing a standard about how to describe Hypermedia APIs. They use RDF, standard vocabs like schema.org and you can write your API specific vocab they call documentation. As far as I understand their model you can give parameters in the documentation for operations represented by hyperlinks. You can use for example XSD to add constraints like numbers, etc. to the parameters. It takes a lot more effort than normally to write this kind of formal documentation and as far as I understand there are currently no general REST clients which could profit from these, so it does not make much sense currently to write such an API, but it is possible if you want to.

As of why to use HATEOAS, it makes your API flexible and backward compatible. For example if somebody does not have permission for an operation, you simply don't send a hyperlink for it in the response. You can always add new operations and the existing clients don't have to support them, they can just focus on what they already know and they won't break because something extra is added. They don't have to know about the URI structures and the methods, which can freely change if the only thing they depend on is the operation type and the parameters.